# Find angle between $y=\sin x$ and $y=\cos x$ at their intersection point.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Find angle between $y=\sin x$ and $y=\cos x$ at their intersection point.

Intersection points are $\frac{\pi}{4}+\pi k$ and to find angle between them we need to compute derivatives at intersection points but then I can't combine them to get an answer which is $\arctan2\sqrt2$. Will be thankful for your help.

Comment: Do you mean you've computed an answer that doesn't agree with your answer sheet, or that you have no idea how to go about it?

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks for giving time .I mean that I computed derivatives at points  but have no idea how combine them to get answer.

Comment: You know the tangents of two angles, and you want to know the difference between the angles, so you should use the formula for the tangent of the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think about these as parametrized curves $(t,\sin t)$ and $(t,\cos t)$, then the angle between them at a point $t_0$ is the angle between $(1,\cos t_0)$ and $(1,-\sin t_0)$. If $t_0 = \frac{\pi}{4} + \pi k$, then we get
$$\cos\theta = \frac{(1,\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})\cdot(1,\mp\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})}{\frac{3}{2}} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{3}.$$
This, of course, yields an angle of $\arccos\frac{1}{3}$, which is the same as $\arctan 2\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $u$ is the angle $$\tan u=\left|\dfrac{\cos x-(-\sin x)}{1+\cos x(-\sin x)}\right|$$

At the point of intersection,

$$\cos x+\sin x=\sqrt2\sin(x+\pi/4)=\cdots=\sqrt2(-1)^n$$

$$\sin x\cos x=\dfrac{\sin2(n\pi+\pi/4)}2=\dfrac12$$

Answer (score 0):

The slope of the tangent line to $y=\sin x$ at $x = \frac{\pi}{4}+\pi k$ is
$$m_s = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\pi k \right)
      = \frac{\cos \pi k - \sin \pi k}{\sqrt 2} = \frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt 2} $$

The slope of the tangent line to $y=\cos x$ at $x = \frac{\pi}{4}+\pi k$ is
$$m_c = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\pi k \right)
      = -\frac{\cos \pi k + \sin \pi k}{\sqrt 2} = -\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt 2} $$

The angle between the two lines is described by

$$ \tan \theta = 
   \left| \dfrac{m_s - m_c}{1 + m_s m_c}\right | 
   = \dfrac{\sqrt 2}{\left(\frac 12 \right)} = 2\sqrt 2$$

So $\theta = \arctan 2\sqrt 2 \approx 70.53^\circ$

Comment: It has close resemblance with my post, right?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee - Yes. That was the idea.

Answer (score 0):

f(x): y=sin(x)
g(x): y=cos(x)
let m1 and m2 be the slopes of f(x) and g(x)
m1 = d(sin(x))/dx = cos(x)
m2 = d(cos(x))/dx = -sin(x)

We know that if k is the angle between two lines with slope ma and mb

Tan(k)=|(ma-mb)/(1+ma*mb)|

At the point of intersection, the angle between the curves is the same as angle between tangents of the curves at the point of intersection (say (x0,y0)) and these tangents have slope f'(x0) and g'(x0).

```
          [f'(x)= d(f(x))/dx and g'(x)=d(g(x))/d(x)]
```

we know x0=pi/4
Therefore at x=pi/4 :

m1=cos(pi/4)=1/sqrt(2)

m2=-sin(pi/4)=-1/sqrt(2)

If @(I don't have theta on my keyboard, sorry) is the angle between f(x) and g(x) at x=pi/4

tan(@)=|(m1-m2)/(1-m1*m2)|

=|{(1/sqrt(2))-[-(1/sqrt(2))]}/{1-(1/sqrt(2)^2)}|

=|{2/sqrt(2)}/{1-(1/2)}|

=|sqrt(2)/(1/2)|

=|2*sqrt(2)|

=2*sqrt(2)

Therefore @=Tan^-1(2*sqrt(2)) or arctan(2*sqrt(2))